# Plotting the Eigenvectors with respect to a parameter

Tags: eigenvalues

I have a matrix $M(\lambda)$ of the form given below with a parameter $\lambda$. I would like to plot the quantity  $$\langle\phi_{i}|Q|\phi_{i}\rangle$$  for every Eigenvectors corresponding to ascending order in Eigenvalues of this matrix with respect $\lambda$.Here $|\phi_{i}\rangle$ are the eigen vector of the matrix $M$.

I am having a  bit of trouble to sort the eigenvectors and plot it w.r.t $\lambda$.

> Could somebody help me to get that.

```
M=[{0.5, 0., 0., 0. + [\lambda], 0.000141421, 0., 0., 0.},{0., -0.5, 0. + \[Lambda], 0., 0., 0.000141421, 0., 0.},
   {0., 0. + \[Lambda], 1.5, 0., 0., 0. + Sqrt[2] \[Lambda], 0.000244949, 0.}, 
  {0. + \[Lambda], 0., 0., 0.5, 0. + Sqrt[2] \[Lambda], 0., 0., 0.000244949},
 {0.000141421, 0., 0., 0. + Sqrt[2] \[Lambda], 2.5, 0., 0., 0. + Sqrt[3] \[Lambda]},
 {0., 0.000141421, 0. + Sqrt[2] \[Lambda], 0., 0., 1.5,0. + Sqrt[3] \[Lambda], 0.},
 {0., 0., 0.000244949, 0., 0., 0. + Sqrt[3] \[Lambda], 3.5, 0.},
  {0., 0., 0., 0.000244949, 0. + Sqrt[3] \[Lambda], 0., 0., 2.5}]
```

The Q Matrix is

```
Q={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
   {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0},
   {0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the norm of the eigenvector"? Eigenvectors are non-unique and are usually normalized to have unit norm for that reason. This is what `Eigenvectors` and `Eigensystem` do for numeric matrices. For matrices involving symbols (like yours), these functions just pick representations that have convenient symbolic forms, which is why they're not usually normalized in that case.

Comment: You could start by `Plot[Eigenvalues[M[\[Lambda]]] // Evaluate, {\[Lambda], 0, 25}]`

Comment: @Chris: I would like to plot norm of the eigenvector not the eigenvalues itself. The eigenvector has to be taken in the ascending order in its eigenvalues.

Comment: @AVM The norm of an eigenvector is a meaningless concept unless you give more detail about constraints on the eigenvectors. If `x` is an eigenvector of `M`, then so is `s*x` for any scalar `s`. You can create eigenvectors of any norm you want.

Comment: @Sjorerd: Thanks for your reply. Here I have done a mistake in writing the question. One operator I have to introduced.

Comment: @AVM So I think you mean you mean that the `|ϕ_i>` are normalized eigenvectors, correct?

Comment: What is `Q`? Please define all symbols needed here.

Comment: In what order should the eigenvalues be? Your matrix `M` is not Hermitian, so the eigenvalues are complex and cannot be ordered in an obvious way.

Comment: I am rectifying my equations. Pl wait

Comment: @Roman and Sjoerd: Pl have a look the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the problem a bit:

```
M[λ_] = {{0.5, 0, 0, λ, 0.000141421, 0, 0, 0},
         {0, -0.5, λ, 0, 0, 0.000141421, 0, 0},
         {0, λ, 1.5, 0, 0, Sqrt[2] λ, 0.000244949, 0},
         {λ, 0, 0, 0.5, Sqrt[2] λ, 0, 0, 0.000244949},
         {0.000141421, 0, 0, Sqrt[2] λ, 2.5, 0, 0, Sqrt[3] λ},
         {0, 0.000141421, Sqrt[2] λ, 0, 0, 1.5, Sqrt[3] λ, 0},
         {0, 0, 0.000244949, 0, 0, Sqrt[3] λ, 3.5, 0},
         {0, 0, 0, 0.000244949, Sqrt[3] λ, 0, 0, 2.5}};

Q = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3}};
```

For a given value of $\lambda$ you can compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and sort them, with

```
es[λ_?NumericQ] := Sort[Transpose[Eigensystem[M[N[λ]]]]]
```

and plot your expectation values with

```
Plot[#[[2]].Q.#[[2]] & /@ es[λ], {λ, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

#### Update

If you only need the three lowest eigenvalues, use `es[λ][[;;3]]`:

```
Plot[#[[2]].Q.#[[2]] & /@ es[λ][[;; 3]], {λ, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

For improved speed (large matrices) you can try to restrict the calculation to the three lowest eigenvalues, instead of calculating all eigenvalues and extracting the three lowest ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This plotting I was expecting.  I would like to know about  Plot[#[[2]]. Is it for the 2nd Eigenvector?

Comment: Pl tell me what does the symbol N signify in [M[N[λ]]]]]  ?

Comment: Please have a look at the official documentations of [Slot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html), [Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), and [N](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Comment: Thanks for your information. If I would like to plot first three eigenvector corresponding to three lowest Eigenvalues, What I have to do?

Comment: This is needed because if I increase the dim. of M matrix, the number of graphs also increases. So If I am interested to first few of them e.g. 3, what I should do? What command I have to modify. Pl let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: @AVM it will also be valuable to look at [Eigensystem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html).

Comment: @Roman:  Plot[#[[2]].Q.#[[2]] & /@ es[λ][[;; 3]], {λ, 0, 1}]      in this case how I can choose the interval of  $\lambda $:  Because whenever  I am choosing {$\lambda$, 0, 1, 0.01} it is not showing the plot. Pl help me to get that.

Comment: @AVM you need the [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) option to set the resolution in a plot. Something like `PlotPoints -> 100`. If you set [`MaxRecursion -> 0`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html), the plot resolution is fixed.

Comment: @Roman : Thanks for your reply. Still I am in confusion where to insert this command. Pl have a look on this        Plot[#[[2]].Q.#[[2]] & /@ es[\[Lambda]][[;; 6]], {\[Lambda], 0, 1, 0.01}, PlotPoints -> 100,   MaxRecursion -> 0]  ........with this some error is occurring.  Pl let me know where to insert this.

Comment: @Roman: Thanks for your advice. Now I resolve that interval issue.